# How to click a link in the PDF with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am facing problem in clicking a link in the PDF. Scenario is to download a PDF and click on the link *click here* and validate opening page title is as expected.

Comment: what is your problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: We need to know more: are you not able to find the link, not getting a response when you click the link, not able to reach the opening page, or not able to find the title of the opening page?

Comment: You want to use Selenium Webdriver to do all of the following: download a PDF, then open the PDF, then click a link titled "click here" in the PDF, an then validate the page title in the PDF.  Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes you are right, but question here is how can i use Selenium Webdriver to click on link in the PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can work only with the webelements, to work with PDF, java Apache provides an API called PDFBox.

You can extract the link using this API and validate it.

1. http://thottingal.in/blog/2009/06/24/pdfbox-extract-text-from-pdf/ - Link to Extract text from PDF usgin PDFBox
2. http://www.printmyfolders.com/Home/PDFBox-Tutorial - Link for Tutorials on PDFBox.
3. https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/ - API docs to explore the classes in the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set to display PDF in a browser (it could be change to do so, or to download a file) some elements of some PDFs are reachable by XPath expressions. Then it is usable even with Selenium-IDE!

For example in Firefox there is object

```
<div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer">
```

with structure inside

```
   <div id="pageContainer1" class="page" ... data-page-number="1">...</div>
   <div id="pageContainer2" class="page" ... data-page-number="2" data-loaded="true">

      <div class="canvasWrapper" ...>...</div>
      <div class="textLayer" ...>...</div>
      <div class="annotationLayer">...</div>

   </div>
</div>
```

If you need the link, you will find it in annotation layer. Another question is to find proper object, as the structure of the PDF file is very flat.

Additionally, the PDF viewer inside the Firefox browser is just a normal web application, so you can even use all the functional buttons and list trough the document and wait till pages get loaded (`data-loaded="true"`), turn pages etc.

But be careful, not each browser will behave the same. I recommend to you to make some research around if this way fills your needs.